# List all merged changesets since last merge?

Tags: mercurial, merge

Using Mercurial, how can I list all the changesets applied by merging a branch, since the last merge from that branch?

Answer (score 4):

Revsets are your friend. Or your nemesis, depending on how complex they get :)

The following command will show all associated changesets between the last two merges:

```
$ hg log -r "first(last(merge(),2)):last(merge()) & ancestors(last(merge()))"
```

That complex little expression (which I'll look at making simpler later) does the following:

- `x:y` gives you all changesets between `x` and `y` inclusive
- `merge()` is a revset that contains all merges.
- `last(...,n)` gives the last n changesets of a set, with `n` defaulting to 1
- `first(...)` gives you the first changeset of a set
- `ancestors(last(merge()))` is a set containing all ancestors of the last merge

Combining all of those, the expression above becomes (ready?): Give me all changesets between the first of the last two merges, and the last merge, inclusive, which happen to be contributing ancestors of the last merge.

The `ancestors(...)` bit filters out any changesets that are not related.

You can limit this to be the changes on a specific branch by adding `& branch(branchname)`.  For example, if you are merging onto a `release` branch from `default`, you could do:

```
$ hg log -r "first(last(merge(),2)):last(merge()) & ancestors(last(merge())) & branch(default)"
```

This wouldn't include the actual merges themselves, as they would appear on the `release` branch.

Hopefully this makes sense - I'll have a look this afternoon to see if I can get a simpler way, but that's the first that springs to mind.  In the meantime, if you use this, you can make it easier by creating a revset alias in your user hgrc file:

```
[revsetalias]
contrib = first(last(merge(),2)):last(merge()) & ancestors(last(merge()))
```

So you can then use:

```
$ hg log -r "contrib"
$ hg log -r "contrib & branch(default)"
```

For more information have a look at `hg help revsets`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. I'll explain why in my answer, but feel free to criticise my answer too.

Comment: @PaulS: Looking at your answer, you could be right - still, it was a good attempt by me :)

Comment: Oh absolutely, and I stole a few bits to make my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure icabod's solution is quite right. Let me see if I can explain.

Let's take this change graph.

```
o----A1----A2----M1--------A3---M2
 \              /              /
  ---B1----B2---              /
      \                      /
       ----C1--------C2----C3
```

`B` is a branch taken from `o`, and `C` is a branch taken from `B1`. If we're at M2 and run icabod's command then:

- `last(merge())` is `M2`
- `first(last(merge(),2))` is `M1`

So the expression becomes:

```
hg log -r "M1:M2 & ancestors(M2)"
```

`M1:M2` is the changes made than have revision numbers between `M1` and `M2`, which in this case is `A3`, `C2` & `C3`, which completely ignores `C1`.

What I think is you're looking for the set of ancestors of M2, that weren't ancestors of M1. i.e.

```
hg log -r "ancestors(M2) & not ancestors(M1)"
```

or

```
hg log -r "ancestors(last(merge())) and not ancestors(first(last(merge(), 2)))"
```

I think this should be `C1`, `C2`, `C3` & `A3`. It also has the advantage that it doesn't care how, or when, change-sets were added to the repo.

*The only problem with this is if the second to last merge isn't an ancestor of the latest merge. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;-)*

---

Of course, all of this can be avoided by doing `hg merge --preview` (or `-P`) prior to doing a merge, and it lists all the change-sets that will be included when you do a merge.

Comment: +1 mainly for mentioning `merge --preview`. Makes me wonder if there should be a similar command for examining a merge _after_ the event, tho' if there were it would be tricky to know where to stop the output... I guess at the point where the two branches branched.

Comment: +1 from me too for mentioning merge --preview. Very helpful. You should be able to get the same information after the merge by simply updating to the merge's first parent and doing a merge --preview with the merge's second parent.